# I wanted to add capturing image by using webcam to my PyQt gui window and webcam image will come on gui window

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, opencv3.0

I wanted to add the webcam image to my main GUI window and that image will send to the email id. If this is not Possible, I also want to save that image and that saved image will send to my email id and On the countdown to 3,2,1, smile it will click the image by webcam.
Here, is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
import cv2, time

DURATION_INT = 5


class MyMainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.time_left_int = DURATION_INT
        self.widget_counter_int = 0

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        central_widget.setLayout(vbox)

        self.pages_qsw = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
        vbox.addWidget(self.pages_qsw)
        self.time_passed_qll = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        vbox.addWidget(self.time_passed_qll)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.pushButton.setText("Push to start")
        self.yesbutton = QtWidgets.QToolButton()
        self.yesbutton.setText("yes")
        self.Nobutton = QtWidgets.QToolButton()
        self.Nobutton.setText("No")

        self.imageframe = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.imageframe.setText("fghkfhh")

        vbox.addWidget(self.Nobutton)
        vbox.addWidget(self.yesbutton)
        vbox.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        vbox.addWidget(self.imageframe)


        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.timer_start)
        self.yesbutton.clicked.connect(self.capturing_image)
        self.update_gui()

    def gmail_alert(self):
        email_user = 'user email_id'
        email_send = 'receiver email_id'

        subject = 'Alert system'

        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['From'] = email_user
        msg['To'] = email_send
        msg['Subject'] = subject
        msg.preamble = "test"

        body = 'Hi there, sending this email from Python!'
        msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

        filename = 'alert.png'
        attachment = open(filename, 'rb')

        part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
        part.set_payload((attachment).read())
        encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; 
                           filename= " + filename)

        msg.attach(part)
        text = msg.as_string()

        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        server.starttls()
        server.login(email_user, 'user email_id password')
        server.sendmail(email_user, email_send, text)
        server.quit()

    def timer_start(self):
        self.time_left_int = DURATION_INT
        self.my_qtimer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.my_qtimer.timeout.connect(self.timer_timeout)
        self.my_qtimer.start(1000)
        self.update_gui()

    def timer_timeout(self):
        if self.time_left_int > 0:
            self.time_left_int -= 1
        else:
            self.gmail_alert()
        self.update_gui()



    def update_gui(self):
        self.time_passed_qll.setText((str(self.time_left_int) if self.time_left_int >=1 else "Smile..!"))

    def capturing_image(self):
        video =cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        check, frame = video.read()

        print(check)
        print(frame)

        cv2.imshow("capturing", frame)
        video.release()

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
main_window = MyMainWindow()
main_window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_()
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?  What are you unable to do? Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I wanted to save the image by clicking yes button on the countdown of 3 and the same image will go to that email.

Comment: How I Merge this two file for creating a single GUI window. As like I created a single .py file. where all working is done just by running a single .py file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you do not have to use `cv2.imshow()` inside PyQt since it blocks the python event loop, if you want to show the image of opencv in PyQt you have to convert it to QImage or QPixmap, the next class implements the data acquisition of opencv and it allows to obtain the QImage but it must be executed in a thread.

**OpencvQt.py**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Capture(QtCore.QObject):
    started = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    frameReady = QtCore.pyqtSignal(np.ndarray)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Capture, self).__init__(parent)
        self._frame = None
        self.m_timer = QtCore.QBasicTimer()
        self.m_videoCapture = cv2.VideoCapture()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def start(self, cam=0):
        if self.m_videoCapture is not None:
            self.m_videoCapture.release()
            self.m_videoCapture = cv2.VideoCapture(cam)
        if self.m_videoCapture.isOpened():
            self.m_timer.start(0, self)
            self.started.emit()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def stop(self):
        self.m_timer.stop()

    def __del__(self):
        self.m_videoCapture.release()

    def frame(self):
        return self.m_frame

    def timerEvent(self, event):
        if event.timerId() != self.m_timer.timerId():
            return

        ret, val = self.m_videoCapture.read()
        if not ret:
            self.m_timer.stop()
            return
        self.m_frame = val    
        self.frameReady.emit(self.m_frame)

    frame = QtCore.pyqtProperty(np.ndarray, fget=frame, notify=frameReady, user=True)

class Converter(QtCore.QObject):
    imageReady = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtGui.QImage)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Converter, self).__init__(parent)
        self.m_frame = np.array([])
        self.m_timer = QtCore.QBasicTimer()
        self.m_processAll = True
        self.m_image = QtGui.QImage()

    def queue(self, frame):
        self.m_frame = frame
        if not self.m_timer.isActive():
            self.m_timer.start(0, self)

    def process(self, frame):
        w, h, _ = frame.shape
        rgbImage = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        self.m_image = QtGui.QImage(rgbImage.data, h, w, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
        self.imageReady.emit(QtGui.QImage(self.m_image))

    def timerEvent(self, event):
        if event.timerId() != self.m_timer.timerId():
            return
        self.process(self.m_frame)
        self.m_timer.stop()

    def processAll(self):
        return self.m_processAll

    def setProcessAll(self, _all):
        self.m_processAll = _all

    def processFrame(self, frame):
        if self.m_processAll:
            self.process(frame)
        else:
            self.queue(frame)

    def image(self):
        return self.m_image

    image = QtCore.pyqtProperty(QtGui.QImage, fget=image, notify=imageReady, user=True)
    processAll = QtCore.pyqtProperty(bool, fget=processAll, fset=setProcessAll)
```

With the above we can show the camera in a QLabel, on the other hand we must convert the QImage to bytes for it we use QByteArray with QBuffer. Another problem that arises is that the sending of email takes a while so the GUI can be blocked so it must be executed in a thread. And finally I added a QDialog where you must enter the mail data.

**main.py**

```
import sys
import threading
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

from OpencvQt import Capture, Converter


config = {
    "DURATION_INT": 5
}

def send_email(user, pwd, recipient, subject, body, image_payload):
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = user
    msg['To'] = recipient
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

    part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')

    part.set_payload(image_payload)
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    filename = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString()+ '.png'
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= " + filename)
    msg.attach(part)
    text = msg.as_string()

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(user, pwd)
    server.sendmail(user, recipient, text)
    server.quit()

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        self.view = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.btn_start = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Start")
        self.btn_stop = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Stop")
        self.btn_send = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Send Email")
        self.label_time = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        lay.addWidget(self.view, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        lay.addWidget(self.btn_start)
        lay.addWidget(self.btn_stop)
        lay.addWidget(self.btn_send)
        lay.addWidget(self.label_time, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.view.setFixedSize(640, 400)
        self.show()
        self.init_camera()
        self.init_email()

    def init_camera(self):
        self.capture = Capture()
        self.converter = Converter()
        captureThread = QtCore.QThread(self)
        converterThread = QtCore.QThread(self)
        self.converter.setProcessAll(False)
        captureThread.start()
        converterThread.start()
        self.capture.moveToThread(captureThread)
        self.converter.moveToThread(converterThread)
        self.capture.frameReady.connect(self.converter.processFrame)
        self.converter.imageReady.connect(self.setImage)
        self.capture.started.connect(lambda: print("started"))
        self.btn_start.clicked.connect(self.capture.start)
        self.btn_stop.clicked.connect(self.capture.stop)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtGui.QImage)
    def setImage(self, image):
        self.view.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image))

    def init_email(self):
        timeline = QtCore.QTimeLine(config["DURATION_INT"]*1000, self)
        timeline.frameChanged.connect(self.onFrameChanged)
        timeline.setFrameRange(0, config["DURATION_INT"])
        timeline.setDirection(QtCore.QTimeLine.Backward)
        self.btn_send.clicked.connect(timeline.start)

        d = EmailDialog(self)
        if d.exec_() == EmailDialog.Accepted:
            self._info = d.get_data()

    def onFrameChanged(self, frame):
        if frame !=0:
            self.label_time.setNum(frame)
        else:
            self.label_time.setText("Smile...!")
            QtWidgets.QApplication.beep()
            image = QtGui.QImage(self.converter.image)
            ba = QtCore.QByteArray()
            buff = QtCore.QBuffer(ba)
            image.save(buff, "PNG")
            th = threading.Thread(target=send_email, args=(*self._info, ba))
            th.start()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.capture.stop()
        super(MainWindow, self).closeEvent(event)


class EmailDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(EmailDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        lay = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self)
        self.from_le = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.pass_le = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(echoMode=QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.to_le = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.subject_le = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.body_te = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()

        self.buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox()
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        lay.addRow("From: ", self.from_le)
        lay.addRow("Password: ", self.pass_le)
        lay.addRow("To: ", self.to_le)
        lay.addRow("Subject: ", self.subject_le)
        lay.addRow("Body: ", self.body_te)
        lay.addRow(self.buttonBox)

        self.from_le.textChanged.connect(self.enable_button)
        self.pass_le.textChanged.connect(self.enable_button)
        self.to_le.textChanged.connect(self.enable_button)
        self.enable_button()

    def enable_button(self):
        disabled = self.from_le.text() == "" or self.pass_le.text() == "" or self.to_le.text() == ""
        self.buttonBox.setDisabled(disabled)

    def get_data(self):
        return self.from_le.text(), self.pass_le.text(), self.to_le.text(), self.subject_le.text(), self.body_te.toPlainText()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks for answering I am new to Pyqt but when I run your code I got an error as no module as opencvqt and many soo errors. So I request you to first run my code in your terminal and then I just want simple GUI window in which there is a single button and by just clicking that push button it will click the image using a webcam or logitech on the countdown of from 5 to smile. and that image will send to email automatically. just like DSLRBooth application. Thanks again

Comment: @priyanshukumar you have to create 2 files: the first one called OpencvQt.py and the other one main.py. Have you read my answer completely?

Comment: when I clicked start button it will start capturing the image but after few seconds it shows tha tPyhton Program is not working and it will automatically close the Gui window.. Please SOlved this error!!!

Comment: @priyanshukumar It seems strange to me that I have tried it and it works correctly, execute it from a terminal or cmd and tell me the error message.

Comment: The error was whenever I clicked the start button after filling in the email data the python stopped working and whole GUI window are closed.

Comment: Thanks @eyllanesc it's working. one thing more I want to ask that instead of showing that count button by clicking into sending mail button, I want that countdown number to the webcam screen frame. please help me for that.

Comment: @priyanshukumar That's another question, create another post. On the other hand if my answer helps you do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, review the [tour], that is the best way to thank