# Unable to stream frames from camera to QML

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qml, pyqt5

I am using PyQT5. I want to send frames from Opencv to QML using QQuickPaintedItem. I wrote a sample implementation here. I cant seem to find why the paint event is called only once, only when the application is loading. It is painting only one frame from the camera to the QML component and the **self.update()** is not calling paint event.

```
from OpenGL import GL
from PyQt5.QtQuick import QQuickPaintedItem, QQuickView
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPixmap, QImage
from PyQt5.QtQml import qmlRegisterType
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl,QObject,pyqtSignal
import cv2.cv2 as cv2
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication


class ImageWriter(QQuickPaintedItem):

    cam_frame = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ImageWriter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)        
        self.setRenderTarget(QQuickPaintedItem.FramebufferObject) 

    def paint(self, painter):
        print(ImageWriter.cam_frame)
        painter.drawPixmap(0,0,ImageWriter.cam_frame)

    def update_frame(self,frame):
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (700, 500), cv2.INTER_AREA)
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
        frame = QImage(frame, frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0], 17)
        ImageWriter.cam_frame = QPixmap.fromImage(frame) 
        self.update()

def get_frames(app):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    num = 0
    imgw = ImageWriter()
    while True:
        while num != 30:
            _ , bgframe = cap.read()
            num += 1
        _ , frame = cap.read()
        imgw.update_frame(frame)            
        print("get frames") 
        app.processEvents()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv) 
    qmlRegisterType(ImageWriter, "imageWriter", 1, 0, "ImageWriter")
    view = QQuickView()
    view.setSource(QUrl('test.qml'))
    rootObject = view.rootObject()
    view.show()
    get_frames(app)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is the QML i wrote for this,

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import imageWriter 1.0

Item {
    width: 800
    height: 600

    ImageWriter  {
        id : imageWriter
        width : 800
        height : 600
    }

}
```

I am quite not able to get why the paint event is not called by **self.update()** . I cant use QWidgets, i have to use this. Is there something i am missing out here ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is caused by having 2 ImageWriter objects, one created in `imgw = ImageWriter()` and the other in QML, you can combine it by adding prints in .py in .qml:

***.py**

```
def get_frames(app):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    num = 0
    imgw = ImageWriter()
    print("Python:", imgw)
    ...
```

***.qml**

```
...
Component.onCompleted: console.log("QML:", imageWriter)
...
```

Output:

```
qml: >>>> ImageWriter(0x55bf2927e770)
Python:  <__main__.ImageWriter object at 0x7fce8e4ff798>
```

As you can see, there are 2 objects that point to different memory addresses, so a possible solution is to create a singleton using [this library](https://github.com/jazzycamel/PyQt5Singleton):

```
from OpenGL import GL
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtQml, QtQuick
import cv2

try: from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtWrapperType
except ImportError:
    from sip import wrappertype as pyqtWrapperType

class Singleton(pyqtWrapperType, type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dict):
        super().__init__(name, bases, dict)
        cls.instance=None

    def __call__(cls,*args,**kw):
        if cls.instance is None:
            cls.instance=super().__call__(*args, **kw)
        return cls.instance


class ImageWriter(QtQuick.QQuickPaintedItem, metaclass=Singleton):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ImageWriter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)        
        self.setRenderTarget(QtQuick.QQuickPaintedItem.FramebufferObject) 
        self.cam_frame = QtGui.QImage()

    def paint(self, painter):
        painter.drawImage(0, 0, self.cam_frame)

    def update_frame(self,frame):
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (700, 500), cv2.INTER_AREA)
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
        frame = QtGui.QImage(frame, frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0], 17)
        self.cam_frame = frame.copy()
        self.update()

def get_frames(app):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    num = 0
    imgw = ImageWriter()
    while True:
        while num != 30:
            _ , bgframe = cap.read()
            num += 1
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret:
            imgw.update_frame(frame)            
            #print("get frames") 
            app.processEvents()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QGuiApplication(sys.argv) 
    QtQml.qmlRegisterType(ImageWriter, "imageWriter", 1, 0, "ImageWriter")
    view = QtQuick.QQuickView()
    view.setSource(QtCore.QUrl('test.qml'))
    rootObject = view.rootObject()
    view.show()
    get_frames(app)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

With the above should work the acquisition of images I think there is a better way, in a few moments I will show a better option.

---

Using [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52476344/6622587) as a base I created a module that implements a handler of the camera using opencv, in addition to a viewer, and a generic class that allows adding filters, for this the project must have the following structure

```
├── main.py
├── main.qml
└── PyCVQML
    ├── cvcapture.py
    ├── cvitem.py
    └── __init__.py
```

**PyCVQML/cvcapture.py**

```
import numpy as np
import threading

import cv2

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtQml

gray_color_table = [QtGui.qRgb(i, i, i) for i in range(256)]


class CVAbstractFilter(QtCore.QObject):
    def process_image(self, src):
        dst = src
        return dst


class CVCapture(QtCore.QObject):
    started = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    imageReady = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    indexChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CVCapture, self).__init__(parent)
        self._image = QtGui.QImage()
        self._index = 0

        self.m_videoCapture = cv2.VideoCapture()
        self.m_timer = QtCore.QBasicTimer()
        self.m_filters = []
        self.m_busy = False

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def start(self, *args):
        if args:
            self.setIndex(args[0])
        self.m_videoCapture.release()
        self.m_videoCapture = cv2.VideoCapture(self._index)
        if self.m_videoCapture.isOpened():
            self.m_timer.start(0, self)
            self.started.emit()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def stop(self):
        self.m_timer.stop()

    def timerEvent(self, e):
        if e.timerId() != self.m_timer.timerId(): return
        ret, frame = self.m_videoCapture.read()
        if not ret:
            self.m_timer.stop()
            return
        if not self.m_busy:
            threading.Thread(target=self.process_image, args=(np.copy(frame),)).start()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(np.ndarray)
    def process_image(self, frame):
        self.m_busy = True
        for f in self.m_filters:
            frame = f.process_image(frame)
        image = CVCapture.ToQImage(frame)
        self.m_busy = False
        QtCore.QMetaObject.invokeMethod(self,
                                        "setImage",
                                        QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection,
                                        QtCore.Q_ARG(QtGui.QImage, image))

    @staticmethod
    def ToQImage(im):
        if im is None:
            return QtGui.QImage()
        if im.dtype == np.uint8:
            if len(im.shape) == 2:
                qim = QtGui.QImage(im.data, im.shape[1], im.shape[0], im.strides[0], QtGui.QImage.Format_Indexed8)
                qim.setColorTable(gray_color_table)
                return qim.copy()

            elif len(im.shape) == 3:
                if im.shape[2] == 3:
                    w, h, _ = im.shape
                    rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                    flip_image = cv2.flip(rgb_image, 1)
                    qim = QtGui.QImage(flip_image.data, h, w, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
                    return qim.copy()
        return QtGui.QImage()

    def image(self):
        return self._image

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtGui.QImage)
    def setImage(self, image):
        if self._image == image: return
        self._image = image
        self.imageReady.emit()

    def index(self):
        return self._index

    def setIndex(self, index):
        if self._index == index: return
        self._index = index
        self.indexChanged.emit()

    @QtCore.pyqtProperty(QtQml.QQmlListProperty)
    def filters(self):
        return QtQml.QQmlListProperty(CVAbstractFilter, self, self.m_filters)

    image = QtCore.pyqtProperty(QtGui.QImage, fget=image, notify=imageReady)
    index = QtCore.pyqtProperty(int, fget=index, fset=setIndex, notify=indexChanged)
```

**PyCVQML/cvitem.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtQuick


class CVItem(QtQuick.QQuickPaintedItem):
    imageChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CVItem, self).__init__(parent)
        # self.setRenderTarget(QtQuick.QQuickPaintedItem.FramebufferObject)
        self.m_image = QtGui.QImage()

    def paint(self, painter):
        if self.m_image.isNull(): return
        image = self.m_image.scaled(self.size().toSize())
        painter.drawImage(QtCore.QPoint(), image)

    def image(self):
        return self.m_image

    def setImage(self, image):
        if self.m_image == image: return
        self.m_image = image
        self.imageChanged.emit()
        self.update()

    image = QtCore.pyqtProperty(QtGui.QImage, fget=image, fset=setImage, notify=imageChanged)
```

**PyCVQML/__init__.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtQml

from .cvcapture import CVCapture, CVAbstractFilter
from .cvitem import CVItem


def registerTypes(uri = "PyCVQML"):
    QtQml.qmlRegisterType(CVCapture, uri, 1, 0, "CVCapture")
    QtQml.qmlRegisterType(CVItem, uri, 1, 0, "CVItem")
```

Then you use it in the `main.py`, I have added 2 example filters, for this `CVCapture` has the filters property where the filters are passed to it, and they will be executed in the order they are established. To implement a new filter you must inherit from `CVAbstractFilter` and overwrite the `process_image()` method that receives the image as an `np.ndarray` and should return the result after the filter.

**main.py**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtQuick, QtQml
import PyCVQML


def max_rgb_filter(image):
    # split the image into its BGR components
    (B, G, R) = cv2.split(image)

    # find the maximum pixel intensity values for each
    # (x, y)-coordinate,, then set all pixel values less
    # than M to zero
    M = np.maximum(np.maximum(R, G), B)
    R[R < M] = 0
    G[G < M] = 0
    B[B < M] = 0

    # merge the channels back together and return the image
    return cv2.merge([B, G, R])


def rgb_to_gray(image):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    return gray


class MaxRGBFilter(PyCVQML.CVAbstractFilter):
    def process_image(self, src):
        return max_rgb_filter(src)


class GrayFilter(PyCVQML.CVAbstractFilter):
    def process_image(self, src):
        return rgb_to_gray(src)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import os
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QGuiApplication(sys.argv)

    PyCVQML.registerTypes()
    QtQml.qmlRegisterType(MaxRGBFilter, "Filters", 1, 0, "MaxRGBFilter")
    QtQml.qmlRegisterType(GrayFilter, "Filters", 1, 0, "GrayFilter")

    view = QtQuick.QQuickView()
    view.setTitle("PyCVQML Example")
    dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)
    view.setSource(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(QtCore.QDir(dir_path).absoluteFilePath("main.qml")))
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import PyCVQML 1.0
import Filters 1.0

Item {
    width: 800
    height: 600

    CVItem  {
        id: imageWriter
        anchors.fill: parent
        image: capture.image
    }

    MaxRGBFilter{
        id: max_rgb_filter
    }
    GrayFilter{
        id: gray_filter
    }

    CVCapture{
        id: capture
        index: 0
        filters: [max_rgb_filter, gray_filter]
        Component.onCompleted: capture.start()
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry,     self.imageChanged.connect(self.update)
TypeError: connect() failed between ImageWriter.imageChanged[] and update()

Comment: Qt5 Version Number is: 5.10.0 
PyQt5 Version is:......5.10 
Sip Version is:........4.19.6

Comment: self.imageChanged.connect(lambda: self.update())
TypeError: connect() failed between ImageWriter.imageChanged[] and unislot()

Comment: It works now. But how to exit the application correctly?

Comment: Windows 10. There is no error. The window was closed, the camera was turned off, but the application in the CMD is hanging.

Comment: unfortunately, the same thing - application in the CMD is hanging.

Comment: In the `stop` method I tried everything I knew, nothing happened. 
Let's try have time one hour.

Comment: @S.Nick I have updated and simplified my code, test if it works correctly, please.

Comment: It works now.
The window was closed, the camera was turned off, but the application in the CMD is hanging.

Comment: @S.Nick I'm going to wait for the feedback from the OP or from another user, maybe it's just a problem your computer, have you tried it in another?

Comment: The traffic ending is:
. . .
  CVItem paint
  CVCapture process_image
  CVCapture matToQImage
  CVCapture setImage
  CVCapture image

  CVItem setImage
  CVCapture process_image
  CVCapture matToQImage
  CVCapture setImage
  CVCapture timerEvent

  CVItem paint
  CVCapture process_image
  CVCapture matToQImage
  CVCapture setImage
  CVCapture image

  CVItem setImage
  CVCapture process_image
  CVCapture matToQImage
  CVCapture setImage
  CVCapture timerEvent
  CVCapture process_image
  CVCapture matToQImage
  CVCapture setImage
  CVCapture image
  CVItem setImage

Comment: At the beginning of each method prescribed print. For example: print ("\ t CVItem setImage").
I close the application: the window closes, the camera goes out, the CMD hangs.
I close CMD - the file in which I make a conclusion is shown. The ending of the issue in the file, see above.

Comment: a really good example. Only thing I found was a missing ")" in main.py, and the fact that you don't stop the processImage thread, which is likely to cause an exception on exit. To do that you need some sort of ```onClosing: { capture.stop() }``` entry in the qml